# How to clear snapshot.data in FutureBuilder before accessing new one

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to use future builder to build my widget depending on the length of my contact.length if my contact is a single person it will create -> SingleRoleWidget, meanwhile if there are more than 1 person it will create -> multipleRole widget. The problem is when there are 2 person and I want to delete one of them. When my widget rebuild to build the SingleRole widget, it will show a glimpse of error.

when I tried to debug I found that the futureBuilder still using the old snapshot.data from the multipleRole futureBuilder and later on it will replace the old data with new one

How can I fix this so that the snapshotData will be cleared or empty first and will rebuild when the right data is provided

Here's a chunk my code:

```
else if (ticketData['solver_id'].length < 1 &&
          ticketData['temp_solver_id'].length == 1) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: getPendingSolver(context: context),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                DevMode.log('my snapshot 23 ${snapshot.data}');
                DevMode.log('my snapshot ${snapshot.data.keys}');
                List tempSolverId = snapshot.data.keys.toList();
                if(tempSolverId[0] != null){
                  DevMode.log('snapshot data key ${tempSolverId[0]}');
                  DevMode.log('snapshot data key 2 ${tempSolverId}');
                  DevMode.log('snapshot data key 3 ${snapshot.data.keys.toList()}');
                  return createSingleRole(
                      context: context,
                      nameText: snapshot.data[tempSolverId[0]]['nickname'],
                      profileLink: snapshot.data[tempSolverId[0]]
                      ['profile_picture_link'] ??
                          '',
                      phoneNumber: snapshot.data[tempSolverId[0]]['mobile_no'],
                      widgetType: 'pending',
                      roleId: tempSolverId[0],
                      titleText: 'solver');
                }else{
                  return SizedBox.shrink();
                }
              } else {
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              }
            });
      }
```

Comment: Any solution for this problem? Async snapshot carries old data and does not refresh with new data.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem. It seems FutureBuilder returns cached data on reload but found that it also sets snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting. Checking this (or perhaps != ConnectionState.done is better) in addition to snapshot.hasData I got the desired behaviour where I could show waiting feedback instead of old data in reload scenario.